# Two Oracle Sum Functions in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Here's my issue.  I have three Oracle tables.

Table Building:

```
Building_Id | Building_Description
----------------------------------
B1          | Building1
```

Table Room:

```
Building_Id | Room_ID | Room_Sqft | Floor_ID
--------------------------------------------
B1          | R1      | 555       | F1
B1          | R2      | 333       | F1
B1          | R3      | 666       | F2
B1          | R4      | 111       | F2
```

Table: Floor

```
Building_Id | Floor_ID | Floor_Sqft
----------------------------------
B1          | F1       | 999
B1          | F2       | 888
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is one set of sums that look like this:

```
Building_Id | Sum_of_Floors | Sum_of_Rooms
------------------------------------------
B1          | 1887          | 1665
```

Since the sum of the rooms on the floor does not equal the total of the floor, it's not as simple as summing the rooms up twice.  Any tips on how to build the query to get what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Building_Id,
       (SELECT SUM(Floor_SqFt)
          FROM Floor f
         WHERE f.Building_ID = b.Building_Id) Sum_of_Floors,
       (SELECT SUM(Room_SqFt)
          FROM Rooms r
         WHERE r.Building_ID = b.Building_Id) Sum_of_Rooms
  FROM building b
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a query such as:

```
select
    building_id,
    sum_floors = (select sum(floor_sqft) from floor f where f.building_id = b.building_id),
    sum_rooms = (select sum(room_sqft) from room r where r.building_id = b.building_id
from building b
```